# TypeError: points must be number pairs

Tags: typeerror

```
def draw_paths2(self):
    points = [node_data['node_pos'] for index,node_data in enumerate(levels.values()) if index <= self.max_level]
    print(points)
    pygame.draw.lines(self.display,'blue',False,points,6)

def draw_paths(self):
    points = []
    for index, node_data in enumerate(levels.values()):
        if index <= self.max_level:
            points.append([node_data['node_pos']])
    print(points)
    pygame.draw.lines(self.display,'RED',False,points,6)
```

#both methods have the same points in list points and only draw_method2 works. Some1 can help?